# Beamer \foocite{} and multiple overlays leads to multiple citation styles

Tags: beamer, biblatex

In a beamer presentation I am using `\footcite{}` in order to give some citations. Unfortunately, I have recognised the following problem which I am not able to solve:
I have a slide containing multiple overlays and only a single citation, i.e.

```
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{<Title>}
    \visible<1->{ 
         Some text with a citation\footcite{citekey}
       
    }
    \visible<2->{ Some more text whithout a citation
    }
    \visible<3>{
            again some more text
       
    }
           
\end{frame}
```

When I look at the slides I have the following citation in the first overlay:

> CITENUMBER AUTHOR “TITLE”. In: BOOK, Page..

The Authors and the title of the book are highlighted in blendedblue (beamer standard).

But on the next overlay (i.e. same slide) I only have

> CITENUMBER AUTHOR “TITLE”

and nothing is highlighted in blendedblue here.
So, any idea how to ensure that citations are equal on every overlay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid the problem by using `\footfullcite` instead of `\footcite`. This will ensure that biblatex will always print the full citation.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \visible<1->{ 
         Some text with a citation\footfullcite{knuth:ct}
       
    }
    \visible<2->{ Some more text whithout a citation
    }
    \visible<3>{
            again some more text
       
    }
           
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively you could switch off the `citetracker`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citetracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \visible<1->{ 
         Some text with a citation\footcite{knuth:ct}
       
    }
    \visible<2->{ Some more text whithout a citation
    }
    \visible<3>{
            again some more text
       
    }
           
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both solutions are working perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @RobinAlpha You're welcome!